# How to import SAS chinese version into Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, sas

I already used `SASmarkdown` package in R to open `sas.exe` IN R,
however my `edm.sas7bdat` contain Chinese words(necessary), it needs to be run in SAS Chinese version.
Do anyone know how to use `enginepath="sas(chinese)"`?

I tried to configure `"C:/Program Files/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sas.exe" -CONFIG "C:/Program Files/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/nls/zh/sasv9.cfg"`
but didn't work.

```
require(SASmarkdown)
##library
saspath <- "C:/Program Files/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sas.exe"
sasopts <- "-nosplash -ls 75"
knitr::opts_chunk$set(engine='sas', engine.path=saspath,
                      engine.opts=sasopts, comment="")
```

```
data new;
set "c:\SAS\Analysis1201\dataset\edm.sas7bdat";
run;
proc print data=new;
run;
```

Comment: You mentioned you tried to add the `-config` command line option, but I don't see that included in the R code you posted.  Did you include that into the value of the `sasopts` variable?

Comment: tried sasopts <- "-nosplash – ls 75 -config 'C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\nls\zh\sasv9.cfg'"  Did not work

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use double back-slashes:

```
sasopts <- "-nosplash – ls 75 -config 'C:\\Program Files\\SASHome\\SASFoundation\\9.4\\nls\\zh\\sasv9.cfg'"
```